# Hey git, what did I just "git add"?

Tags: git

Often I'm working on a project, then get called away for some emergency, then when I return I realize that I have uncommitted changes, and **I don't remember what I just did**.

This interferes with my desire to leave [good commit messages](http://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/).

There is a sequence of commands which does what I want:

```
$ git stash
$ git stash show -p  # here I see the diff and all is right with the world
$ git stash pop
```

But I dislike all the destructive stashing and popping for the sake of doing a (non-destructive) view.

Is there a version of the above commands that gives the desired result (view the diff) without making destructive changes to the repo?

Comment: It's unbelievable that you missed git diff. Are you trolling?

Comment: @hek2mgl The output of `git diff` will show you changes, but it won't necessarily convey much high-level intent.

Comment: @hek2mgl for crying out loud, what are the odds that *the exact right git command for this specific thing* is the short, obvious one?!  This is a new experience for me.  Sort of embarrassed to admit that I wasn't trolling.

Comment: @hoosierEE Don't worry, that's fine! Have fun with your new `git diff` superpowers! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git diff` will do what you need (this will show the changes in files not committed and not staged)

If you want also staged files `git diff --staged`

However you can also commit with a `[WIP]` message that you can edit after by doing a `fixup` or a `squash` of your commits